# Error while inserting object into database

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb while inserting object into database it is giving error `ReferenceError: WriteResult is not defined`

```
> use school
switched to db school
> student = { "name":"binit", "age": 24, "subjects": ["math", "science", "litrature"] }
{
    "name" : "binit",
    "age" : 24,
    "subjects" : [
        "math",
        "science",
        "litrature"
    ]
}
> db.school.insert(student)
> WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
Fri Jul 17 15:49:17.038 ReferenceError: WriteResult is not defined
```

Comment: Why are you executing `WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })` on the shell command line?

Comment: I am just new to it dont know how to execute just trying it

Comment: `db.school.insert(student)` already inserts your data in collection named as `school` in db `school`. You need to do refer [official site](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/crud-introduction/) for basics.

Comment: Sound's like you "copy/paste" some data in and had a `tab` char or something. If you type "type" ( with your hands ) everything in then there is no error.